# I used malloc(0) for a pointer to char, and my code works. Why is that?

Tags: c, malloc

I created an array of pointers to `char`. I used `malloc(0)` to allocate memory for those pointers.

After that, I used `scanf()` to enter exactly one word to the bytes allocated by `malloc(0` and it worked.

Why is that?

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: Whst do you mean? Provide a [mcve].

Comment: That is undefined behavior .Anything can happen .You can't gurantee this behavior .

Answer (score 5):

First of all, from the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) for `malloc()`, (*emphasis mine*)

> If size is 0, then `malloc()` returns either `NULL`, **or a unique pointer value that can later be successfully passed to `free()`**.

So, it's not guaranteed that `malloc(0)` will return NULL, always. So, your NULL check may not be a success.

Then, to answer

> *Why is that?*

because, in case `malloc(0)` returns a pointer other han NULL, it is only fit to be used as an argument to a later call to `free()`, nothing else. In your case, you're trying to write *into* the memory. Doing so is essentially attempt to write into an *invalid memory*, a memory which not allocated to your program. This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

**The *real beauty* of UB is that, sometimes, program invoking UB *appear* to work *just fine*.**

Comment: So what you are saying is that if he did that in an endless loop, in one of the iterations it would crash?

Comment: @Avra It may, very well. :)